# Casting MyClass<T> to MyClass<object> C#

Tags: c#, generics, events, casting

I have been having some trouble implementing an EventHandler in C# I can't seem to cast `Action<T>` to `Action<object>` for storage in a list.

```
private readonly IList<Action<object>> listeners;

public EventHandler() {
    listeners = new List<Action<object>>();
}

public void RegisterListener<T>(Action<T> listener) where T : class {
        Listeners.Add((Action<object>)listener);
    }

private void ReciveEvent(object evt) {
       if (evt != null)
            Listeners.Where(l => l.GetGeneric(0).
            IsAssignableFrom(evt.GetType())).
            AsParallel().ForAll(l => l(evt));
     }
```

I just get a cast exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action`1[Events.SendTestEvent]' to type 'System.Action`1[System.Object]'.

Events.SendTestEvent <- My current test object... it is just a class with a single property and no parent(besides obj)
```

Comment: Why not define `T` at the class level, so that `listeners` can be declared as `IList<Action<T>>`. then you don't need to cast.

Comment: @sstan ah, because I would like to be able to an event of any kind, so IList<Action<object>> might contain both an Action<SendTestEvent> and Action<TestEvent>. Code I use for doing that. http://hastebin.com/betiquyavi.coffee

Comment: It might be helpful to edit the question to include how you intend to use `listeners`.  It's not immediately clear to me how useful it is to have a list of `Action<object>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is cast an `Action<T>` into an `Action<object>`, which isn't possible. You can make a new Action that triggers the action passed by the method and insert that into your list like this:

```
public void RegisterListener<T>(Action<T> listener) where T : class 
{
    Action<object> wrappingAction = (arg)=>
    {
       var castArg = arg as T;
       if(castArg != null)
       {
           listener(castArg);
       }
    };

    Listeners.Add(wrappingAction);    
}
```

**Note:** This will only trigger the listeners if the object can be cast to the accepted parameter type, however, this is fairly inefficient (as you'd be casting for each listener listening for that type)

Comment: Oh I see, so there is no concept of 'unchecked' like in java? Thanks this looks good. How would I be able to later remove from the list if I wrapped like this? http://hastebin.com/eyufojiseq.xml

Comment: @TheMineBench if you're talking about in terms of exceptions that's not what is happening here:  the `as` keyword will try to cast and if it cannot then will return null instead of throwing an exception

Comment: https://github.com/TheExerosisGaming/EventFramework/blob/master/src/main/java/me/exerosis/event/EventManager.java#L21 I guess I don't really understand what generics are in C#. They seem to be runtime instead of just being being removed. Is there a standard way to handle generic events like this?

Comment: @TheMineBench a standard way would to either have the caller specify a token or generate a token internally and return it from RegisterListener. Then the token can be used to unregister the callback. The callbacks are then stored in a Dictionary instead of a List.

Comment: @mikez Oh I see, I will give that a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

An `Action<object>` is a method that can accept *anything* as it's parameter.  An `Action<T>` is an object that can accept *only an object of type `T`* as its parameter.  If you could treat an `Action<T>` as an `Action<object>` then you could pass an object that isn't of type `T`, but that action *can't accept objects that aren't of type `T`*, so the compiler prohibits you from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because it wouldn't be safe. It would allow you to do

```
RegisterListener<string>(s => { Console.WriteLine(s); });
Action<object> a = listeners[0];
a(3);
```

You could wrap the given handler in one which casts to the target type on invocation e.g.

```
public void RegisterListener<T>(Action<T> listener) where T : class {
    Listeners.Add(o => { listener((T)o); });
}
```